Custom font not working in @react-pdf/pdf Vite Typescript
I am building a React Vite Application and using @react-pdf/pdf.
I want to add custom font files which are .ttf
I import my font files from where they are. The path is correct:
import PrometoBold from '../../../../assets/fonts/Prometo-Bold.ttf';
import PrometoMedium from '../../../../assets/fonts/Prometo-Medium.ttf';
import PrometoRegular from '../../../../assets/fonts/Prometo-Regular.ttf';
import PrometoLightItalic from '../../../../assets/fonts/Prometo-LightItalic.ttf';

//Register 
Font.register({family: 'PrometoRegular', src: PrometoRegular });
Font.register({family: 'PrometoLightItalic', src: PrometoLightItalic });  
Font.register({family: 'PrometoMedium', src: PrometoMedium }); 
Font.register({family: 'PrometoBold', format: 'truetype', src: PrometoBold }); 

Then I use them in my:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'PrometoBold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#001C43',
        fontSize: 24,
        marginBottom: 10
    }
});

Then doing this:
const PdfDocument = () => {
    return(
        <Document>
            <Page key={index} size="A4" style={styles.page} wrap={true}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>This my title</Text>
            </Page>
        </Document>
    );
};
export default PdfDocument;

But for a strange reason now the PDF isn't being generated anymore.
When removing the line fontFamily: 'PrometoBold', it is generated again but without the font.

I am exactly not sure what is the problem occurred to loading font in your application.
Here are some tips that i can share with you, hope it will help you.
Recently i did a project that about some templates design using react-pdf.

I stored all of my custom fonts inside the public folder, for example: public/assets/fonts.
Then, I grouped them using this format:

Font.register({
   family: "Rockwell",
   fonts: [
       { src: "/fonts/rockwell/rockwell400.ttf" }, // font-style: normal, font-weight: normal
       { src: "/fonts/rockwell/RockwellBold700.ttf", fontWeight: 700 },
   ],
});


Finally, I used them in this format:

textStyle: {
       ...otherStyles,
       fontFamily: "Rockwell",
   },


hi, this returns unknown font format. I am completely lost because i have another application with the same configuration where it does work??
